# i am not able to checked on checkbox

Tags: jquery

```js
(window).scroll(function() {
  ('#menu-open').prop('checked', true);
 
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #8bc34a;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration:none;
  
}

h1, h2, h3, h4 {
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 130px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 3em;
}

.menu {
  filter: url("#goo");
}

.menu-item, .menu-open-button {
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  margin-left: -40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
 
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transition: transform ease-out 200ms;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 40px 40px;
background-position: 20px 10px;
}

.menu-open {
  display: none;
}

.hamburger {
  width: 25px;
  height: 3px;
  background: #83ccaf;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -12.5px;
  margin-top: -1.5px;
  transition: transform 200ms;
}

.hamburger-1 {
  transform: translate3d(0, -8px, 0);
}

.hamburger-2 {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.hamburger-3 {
  transform: translate3d(0, 8px, 0);
}

.menu-open:checked + .menu-open-button .hamburger-1 {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate(45deg);
}
.menu-open:checked + .menu-open-button .hamburger-2 {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale(0.1, 1);
}
.menu-open:checked + .menu-open-button .hamburger-3 {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate(-45deg);
}

.menu {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -190px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 190px;
  width: 380px;
  height: 250px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: left;
}


.menu-item:nth-child(3) {
  transition-duration: 180ms;
}
.menu-item:nth-child(4) {
  transition-duration: 180ms;
}
.menu-item:nth-child(5) {
  transition-duration: 180ms;
}
.menu-item:nth-child(6) {
  transition-duration: 180ms;
}
.menu-item:nth-child(7) {
  transition-duration: 180ms;
}
.menu-item:nth-child(8) {
  transition-duration: 180ms;
}
.menu-item:nth-child(9) {
  transition-duration: 180ms;
}
.menu-item:nth-child(10) {
  transition-duration: 180ms;
}
.menu-item:nth-child(11) {
  transition-duration: 180ms;
}

.menu-open-button {
  z-index: 2;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  transition-duration: 400ms;
  transform: scale(1.1, 1.1) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-open-button:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2, 1.2) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.menu-open:checked + .menu-open-button {
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  transition-duration: 200ms;
  transform: scale(0.8, 0.8) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.menu-open:checked ~ .menu-item {
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.935, 0, 0.34, 1.33);
}
.menu-open:checked ~ .menu-item:nth-child(3) {
  transition-duration: 180ms;
  transform: translate3d(0.10352247px, -129.99995878px, 0);
  background-image: url(img/website.png);
}
.menu-open:checked ~ .menu-item:nth-child(4) {
  transition-duration: 280ms;
  transform: translate3d(91.96047499px, -91.88727354px, 0);
   background-image: url(img/mobileapp.png);
}
.menu-open:checked ~ .menu-item:nth-child(5) {
  transition-duration: 380ms;
  transform: translate3d(130px, 0px, 0);
   background-image: url(img/mailer.png);
}
.menu-open:checked ~ .menu-item:nth-child(6) {
  transition-duration: 480ms;
  transform: translate3d(91.96047499px, 91.88727354px, 0);
   background-image: url(img/digital-marketing.png);
}
.menu-open:checked ~ .menu-item:nth-child(7) {
  transition-duration: 580ms;
  transform: translate3d(0.10352247px, 129.99995878px, 0);
   background-image: url(img/Untitled-2.png);
}
.menu-open:checked ~ .menu-item:nth-child(8) {
  transition-duration: 680ms;
  transform: translate3d(-91.81401383px, 92.03361812px, 0);
   background-image: url(img/ticket.png);
}
.menu-open:checked ~ .menu-item:nth-child(9) {
  transition-duration: 780ms;
  transform: translate3d(-129.99983512px, 0.20704488px, 0);
   background-image: url(img/networking.png);
}
.menu-open:checked ~ .menu-item:nth-child(10) {
  transition-duration: 880ms;
  transform: translate3d(-92.10670289px, -91.74069589px, 0);
   background-image: url(img/analytics.png);
}
.menu-open:checked ~ .menu-item:nth-child(11) {
  transition-duration: 980ms;
  transform: translate3d(-0.31056715px, -129.99962903px, 0);
   background-image: url(img/website.png);
}

.menu a p{
font-family: 'Montserrat';
color: #83ccaf;
font-size: 15px;
margin-top: 47px;
line-height:12px 
}
```

```html
<div style="height:700px;background:red;width:100%;"></div>
<div class="menu"  id="gola">
  <input type="checkbox" href="#" class="menu-open" name="menu-open" id="menu-open" />
  <label class="menu-open-button" for="menu-open">
    <span class="hamburger hamburger-1"></span>
    <span class="hamburger hamburger-2"></span>
    <span class="hamburger hamburger-3"></span>
  </label>
  
  <a href="#" class="menu-item"> <p>Event website</p> </a>
  <a href="#" class="menu-item"> <p>Event App</p> </a>
  <a href="#" class="menu-item"> <p>Emails</p> </a>
  <a href="#" class="menu-item"> <p>Digital Post</p> </a>
  <a href="#" class="menu-item"> <p>Custom forms</p></a>
  <a href="#" class="menu-item"> <p>Event Ticketing</p> </a>
  <a href="#" class="menu-item"> <p>Networking</p> </a>
   <a href="#" class="menu-item"> <p>Analytics</p> </a>
</div>


<!-- filters -->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
    <defs>
      <filter id="shadowed-goo">
          
          <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" result="blur" stdDeviation="10" />
          <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 18 -7" result="goo" />
          <feGaussianBlur in="goo" stdDeviation="3" result="shadow" />
          <feColorMatrix in="shadow" mode="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 1 -0.2" result="shadow" />
          <feOffset in="shadow" dx="1" dy="1" result="shadow" />
          <feComposite in2="shadow" in="goo" result="goo" />
          <feComposite in2="goo" in="SourceGraphic" result="mix" />
      </filter>
      <filter id="goo">
          <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" result="blur" stdDeviation="10" />
          <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 18 -7" result="goo" />
          <feComposite in2="goo" in="SourceGraphic" result="mix" />
      </filter>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

when i am scrolling on perticular div(id="gola") my checkbox is not checked automatically so i can't find solution.i can use scroll on jquery function but it s not working.it checked manually.i can add trigger event on scrolling perticular div.

Comment: Missing $ before (window) :)

Comment: and missing `$` before `('#menu-open')`  -- and missing jQuery lib

Comment: any console errors?

Comment: i know but my question when  i am reaching on perticular div(id="gola")  at that time checkbox is not checked automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You missing jQuery object name use `jQuery` before selecting elements, or just alias `$`.

Also read [How can I debug my JavaScript code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code)

Fixed snippet below:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() { // missing $
  $('#menu-open').prop('checked', true); // missing $
 
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #8bc34a;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration:none;
  
}

h1, h2, h3, h4 {
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 130px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 3em;
}

.menu {
  filter: url("#goo");
}

.menu-item, .menu-open-button {
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  margin-left: -40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
 
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transition: transform ease-out 200ms;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 40px 40px;
background-position: 20px 10px;
}

.menu-open {
  display: none;
}

.hamburger {
  width: 25px;
  height: 3px;
  background: #83ccaf;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -12.5px;
  margin-top: -1.5px;
  transition: transform 200ms;
}

.hamburger-1 {
  transform: translate3d(0, -8px, 0);
}

.hamburger-2 {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.hamburger-3 {
  transform: translate3d(0, 8px, 0);
}

.menu-open:checked + .menu-open-button .hamburger-1 {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate(45deg);
}
.menu-open:checked + .menu-open-button .hamburger-2 {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale(0.1, 1);
}
.menu-open:checked + .menu-open-button .hamburger-3 {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate(-45deg);
}

.menu {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -190px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 190px;
  width: 380px;
  height: 250px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: left;
}


.menu-item:nth-child(3) {
  transition-duration: 180ms;
}
.menu-item:nth-child(4) {
  transition-duration: 180ms;
}
.menu-item:nth-child(5) {
  transition-duration: 180ms;
}
.menu-item:nth-child(6) {
  transition-duration: 180ms;
}
.menu-item:nth-child(7) {
  transition-duration: 180ms;
}
.menu-item:nth-child(8) {
  transition-duration: 180ms;
}
.menu-item:nth-child(9) {
  transition-duration: 180ms;
}
.menu-item:nth-child(10) {
  transition-duration: 180ms;
}
.menu-item:nth-child(11) {
  transition-duration: 180ms;
}

.menu-open-button {
  z-index: 2;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  transition-duration: 400ms;
  transform: scale(1.1, 1.1) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-open-button:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2, 1.2) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.menu-open:checked + .menu-open-button {
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  transition-duration: 200ms;
  transform: scale(0.8, 0.8) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.menu-open:checked ~ .menu-item {
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.935, 0, 0.34, 1.33);
}
.menu-open:checked ~ .menu-item:nth-child(3) {
  transition-duration: 180ms;
  transform: translate3d(0.10352247px, -129.99995878px, 0);
  background-image: url(img/website.png);
}
.menu-open:checked ~ .menu-item:nth-child(4) {
  transition-duration: 280ms;
  transform: translate3d(91.96047499px, -91.88727354px, 0);
   background-image: url(img/mobileapp.png);
}
.menu-open:checked ~ .menu-item:nth-child(5) {
  transition-duration: 380ms;
  transform: translate3d(130px, 0px, 0);
   background-image: url(img/mailer.png);
}
.menu-open:checked ~ .menu-item:nth-child(6) {
  transition-duration: 480ms;
  transform: translate3d(91.96047499px, 91.88727354px, 0);
   background-image: url(img/digital-marketing.png);
}
.menu-open:checked ~ .menu-item:nth-child(7) {
  transition-duration: 580ms;
  transform: translate3d(0.10352247px, 129.99995878px, 0);
   background-image: url(img/Untitled-2.png);
}
.menu-open:checked ~ .menu-item:nth-child(8) {
  transition-duration: 680ms;
  transform: translate3d(-91.81401383px, 92.03361812px, 0);
   background-image: url(img/ticket.png);
}
.menu-open:checked ~ .menu-item:nth-child(9) {
  transition-duration: 780ms;
  transform: translate3d(-129.99983512px, 0.20704488px, 0);
   background-image: url(img/networking.png);
}
.menu-open:checked ~ .menu-item:nth-child(10) {
  transition-duration: 880ms;
  transform: translate3d(-92.10670289px, -91.74069589px, 0);
   background-image: url(img/analytics.png);
}
.menu-open:checked ~ .menu-item:nth-child(11) {
  transition-duration: 980ms;
  transform: translate3d(-0.31056715px, -129.99962903px, 0);
   background-image: url(img/website.png);
}

.menu a p{
font-family: 'Montserrat';
color: #83ccaf;
font-size: 15px;
margin-top: 47px;
line-height:12px 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="height:700px;background:red;width:100%;"></div>
<div class="menu"  id="gola">
  <input type="checkbox" href="#" class="menu-open" name="menu-open" id="menu-open" />
  <label class="menu-open-button" for="menu-open">
    <span class="hamburger hamburger-1"></span>
    <span class="hamburger hamburger-2"></span>
    <span class="hamburger hamburger-3"></span>
  </label>
  
  <a href="#" class="menu-item"> <p>Event website</p> </a>
  <a href="#" class="menu-item"> <p>Event App</p> </a>
  <a href="#" class="menu-item"> <p>Emails</p> </a>
  <a href="#" class="menu-item"> <p>Digital Post</p> </a>
  <a href="#" class="menu-item"> <p>Custom forms</p></a>
  <a href="#" class="menu-item"> <p>Event Ticketing</p> </a>
  <a href="#" class="menu-item"> <p>Networking</p> </a>
   <a href="#" class="menu-item"> <p>Analytics</p> </a>
</div>


<!-- filters -->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
    <defs>
      <filter id="shadowed-goo">
          
          <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" result="blur" stdDeviation="10" />
          <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 18 -7" result="goo" />
          <feGaussianBlur in="goo" stdDeviation="3" result="shadow" />
          <feColorMatrix in="shadow" mode="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 1 -0.2" result="shadow" />
          <feOffset in="shadow" dx="1" dy="1" result="shadow" />
          <feComposite in2="shadow" in="goo" result="goo" />
          <feComposite in2="goo" in="SourceGraphic" result="mix" />
      </filter>
      <filter id="goo">
          <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" result="blur" stdDeviation="10" />
          <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 18 -7" result="goo" />
          <feComposite in2="goo" in="SourceGraphic" result="mix" />
      </filter>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: i know but my question is when i am reching on div(gola) that time checkboxed is cheked